# Setting up synergy (multi-computer shared input devices) new to Mac

Tags: macos, synergy

I've just gotten a Mac and the first thing I'm trying to do in setting it up for dev is to set-up synergy.

I've run into countless issues, and am making progress, but that 'Mac's just work' theory is getting tired really fast.

I'd prefer running the Mac as the server, as it's a desktop. why use my PC(laptop) as the server.

So I downloaded synergy, and tried to edit the 'synergy.conf' file. First with textmate, then with Apple script. Neither of these applications will open the file. Even after changing textmate to use plain text format and switching off a few other things to make it into a plain text editor. No good.

Isn't that what these script/text editors are for?

Then I found SyneryKM which is a package to run synergy on osx. 
Took LOTS of fiddling, but I think I finally  got it figured out.

I've got my PC& m\Mac both running synergy. However, my PC will only connect to synergy using the IP address. No problem, however, my Mac won't connect to itself as a synergy server using the IP address. If I use the IP address as a screen in the 'server configuration file', I get a 'Error: unknown screen name `mymac`'.

I know this shouldn't be super complicated, and possibly not the place to find answers about synergy, but I couldn't find a better place, and there has been some talk of synergy here.

Comment: thanks for that ben s & adamalex, i know i've seen non-programming related questions before (though this was kinda programming, because I am still trying to figure out why I can't edit sys files), but i didn' t realize their was a not-programming-related category. I'll use that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Synergy between Mac and Windows and agree with your choice to use SynergyKM; it worked great for me!  There are probably several possible answers for this, but maybe the simplest would be to return your Mac's configuration file to the way it was, then add an entry to your hosts file on your Windows machine.  In case you're not familiar with that you should be able to find it at %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts then add a line that looks like this:

```
123.123.123.123    mymac
```

(of course, you would replace 123.123.123.123 with the actual IP of your Mac)

This change would allow you to connect to your Mac using the hostname 'mymac'

Hope this helps!

Adam

Comment: thanks Adam, I'm not sure if that helps or not. I've made the change on my pc, but now SynergyKM won't start-up on the mac. the status goes to 'starting up', but then i can see the process crash in the activity monitor. i've rebooted, but can't get it to run :(

Comment: ok! i'm typing this with the keyboard on my mac (on my pc no less), so i got it working. though not with synergykm. i had to download text wrangler to edit the text file, had to append .local to the end of my mac screenname mymac.local, as well as your recommended redirect of ip. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it's working!  Coming from a Windows background myself learning the Mac perspective can be a bit of an adjustment but also a lot of fun at times.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the screens first.  Use the hostnames given by OS X.  (IP addresses can be a pain so I do not use them).
To get your host name on OS X : System Preferences -> Sharing

Note:
spaces change to dashes and you must append ".local" on the end.

For example, I see "HellSpawn OverLord" in Sharing, but in my conf file below I use "HellSpawn-OverLord.local"

in windows, bring up a command prompt and type "hostname"

Also you should be able to open the .conf file in TextEdit.  Not sure what TextMate is and AppleScript is an IDE for OSAscript.

Finally make sure you use TABS and do not skip lines.

Synergy can be very finicky.

```
section: screens
    HellSpawn-OverLord.local:
    kordikam-ws:
    Win7:
    Macintosh.local:
end
section: links  
    HellSpawn-OverLord.local:
        left = kordikam-ws
        right = Win7
    Win7:
        left = HellSpawn-OverLord.local
        right = kordikam-ws
    kordikam-ws:
        left = Win7
        right  = HellSpawn-OverLord.local
end
```